# Serving specific remote path if remote path does not exists via proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I've been troubleshooting this for almost half a day now. :(

On the Nginx running on my laptop where I don't use proxy_pass, the try files is working great. The Javascript web app I wrote does client routing when page is loaded. However, if webpage is refreshed, it's the server that receives the request.

I have this configuration in my Nginx running on my laptop

```
location /viewer {
  try_files $uri /viewer/index.html;
}
```

With the config above, if I requested http://localhost/viewer/getservice which does not exists on my file system, I will be served with /viewer/index.html. It's working great!

However, we have a different configuration at work. All our static files/html pages are stored in an upstream S3 bucket.

This is our work configuration

```
location /viewer {
  proxy_pass http://s3-bucket-server/viewer;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_header;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Origin,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}
```

The configuration above works great when I access it like this, `http://internal-app.docs.svr/viewer`. I can click on our left navigation which changes the location path on the client side to like

```
http://internal-app.docs.svr/viewer/settings
http://internal-app.docs.svr/viewer/docs
http://internal-app.docs.svr/viewer/permissions
etc
```

However, if let's say I was in `http://internal-app.docs.svr/viewer/permissions` and I clicked the browser, what normally happens is that it does a GET call on /viewer/permissions on our web server internal-app.docs.svr. Unfortunately, there is no nginx location rule that will handle that.

What I'd like to achieve is that when the above scenario happens(a 404), have nginx serve /viewer/index.html. I don't want a redirect since I want to keep the last path I was at. In this case, it was `/viewer/permissions`. The javascript app I wrote will handle `/viewer/permissions` eventually.

Comment: Finally I got it working using error_page. After almost half a day!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working using the config below

```
error_page 404 @proxy;
```

then

```
location @proxy {
  rewrite ^ /viewer/index.html break;
  proxy_pass http://s3-bucket-server;
}
```